# Route returns blank page when returning, but loads on page refresh in Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, asynchronous, refactoring

I want to know why this works. I hate fixing things and not knowing what I just fixed.

While refactoring code I came upon a bug I've seen before where the route loaded, but the component didn't execute. I have a simple blog page that lazy loads a list of blogs. This works fine until you open a blog from the list, then return to the list of blogs, which comes up blank.

I used to use an RXJS subscribe function, but after hearing an NG-Conf talk about letting the Async pipe unwrap the observable in the HTML view. So I decided to try it out. This eliminates the need for subscribe/unsubscribe since Async does this for you.

This is my original bit of code in the blog detail component.

```
      ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.blogService.blogs$.subscribe();
        this.blog$ = this.route.params
          .switchMap(param =>  this.blogService.getBlog(param.id));
      }
```

Then I simply set the service to a local variable. This is outside the ngOnInit.

```
    blog$ = this.blogService.blogs$
```

That worked, but I needed the id for the blog so I tried this.

```
     blog$ = this.blogService.blogs$ = this.route.params
            .switchMap(param =>  this.blogService.getBlog(param.id));
```

I have a simple back button that takes you to the /blog route, which worked fine before, but now of course loads a blank page.

After staring blankly at my computer for a while I finally tried this.

```
     blog$ = this.blogService.blogs$;

     ngOnInit() {
           this.blog$ = this.route.params
           .switchMap(param => this.blogService.getBlog(param.id));
      }
```

I'm assuming that the ngOnInit life cycle hook is setting the id as before, but I don't understand why this would get stuck on the first version, then work after a page refresh.

Edited typo

Comment: Are you routing to the same page you are currently on?

Comment: Can you share your router setup?

Comment: App-route has 
                 { path: 'blog',  loadChildren: () => BlogModule },

blog.module has 
                   { path: '', component: BlogsComponent },
                   { path: ':id', component: BlogComponent }
Is this what your asking for? And no @Nicholas K. The blog detail page for lack of a better term is loaded, the return route back to Blogs was coming up blank and would remain blank on all links. So the Navbar behaved the same way. Even if I manually typed the route into the address bar.